# MATLAB: Undefined function for input arguments

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

I am trying to run the following class:

```
classdef HelloWorld
    properties
        var;
        array;
    end

    methods
        function h = HelloWorld()
            h.var = 30;
            setArray(h);
            disp(h.array(10));
        end

        function setVar(h)
            for i=1:h.var
                h.array(i) = i*2;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I get the following error message:

```
Undefined function 'setArray' for input
arguments of type 'HelloWorld'.

Error in HelloWorld (line 13)
            setArray(h);
```

Comment: Where is `setArray` defined?

Comment: Are you getting `setArray` and `setVar` mixed up?  You call `setArray` in the `HelloWorld` constructor, but I only see a definition for `setVar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `setArray` defined-

```
methods
    function setArray(h)
      %% code
    end
end
```